# How to remember user login on a website

Tags: php, passwords, account

I am trying to create user accounts for my website(To store preferences and data) and I am wondering if anyone could help me with two things.

First, I have looked around a lot, but cannot seem to find any good resources on creating user accounts for a website(all of the web results seem to be about user accounts on a computer or server), so if anyone could suggest a good resource to learn about creating user accounts, that would be great.

Second, what is the best way to remember if a user is logged in? Right now, I have a database that stores users with their emails, passwords and other data. I am wondering how I can check on each page to see who the user is(after they have logged in). Would I use a cookie for this?

If so, how would that work? Would the cookie store their username and password? That does not seem very secure but it is the only way I can think of at the moment.

Comment: What's your website programmed in? That will pretty much tell you what authentication technologies are available.

Comment: I access the database through php and use mysql

Comment: Add user information to database and check if it exists while user logs in. Also see information about `$_SESSION`, which allows you to keep users signed in. Just search over the internet, you can start from PHP registration form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a webpage with user accounts, what do I need to keep in mind?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076993/creating-a-webpage-with-user-accounts-what-do-i-need-to-keep-in-mind)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Login/Registration/User Management Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562715/php-login-registration-user-management-script) Yes, as @loler mentioned, you need to look into $_SESSION and $_COOKIE things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search of [PHP User Management Scripts](https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+user+management+scripts) brings out these following results:

- [Free PHP User Management Script: LOG.ME.IN](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/free-php-user-management-script-log-me-in/)
- [Repox/Simple Users](https://github.com/Repox/SimpleUsers)
- [Many at PHP.ResourseIndex.com](http://php.resourceindex.com/Complete_Scripts/User_Management/Password_Protection/)

Although you may need to customize each and every one according to your requirements.

For sure you need to see [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and [$_COOKIE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).

Answer (score 1):

I bet you could find some resources for developing a user membership system.

Basically you can use **sessions** and **cookies**.

You're right that cookies are not very secure for storing usernames and passwords, but you can store only one cookie with the user ID.

### Resources

[User membership with PHP | Nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/user-membership-with-php/)

[MySQL & PHP User accounts | Pete's web design blog](http://pgiammarco.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/mysql-php-user-accounts-part-1.html)