# How safe is openID?

Tags: security, authentication, openid

Is this something that can be used for highly secure information or should it be bypassed for a single site authentication system? This may be a stupid question (as it does not sound secure) but I would like some advice.

Comment: What sounds "not secure" about it?

Comment: The fact that it sounds like it is so easy to impliment, and you rely on the other site to do thier authentication properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenID itself is no less secure than the traditional username+password login.

Obviously, you're entrusting a large part of the security to the provider - e.g. brute force prevention, password size policy, etc.

Wouldn't use it for online banking for example, not while the OpenID protocol itself is insecure, but due to the use case.

> highly secure information

Financial info? DoD Top Secret? Really secure information isn't available via the internet, only on the local network or through a VPN, which is moving a chunk of the security to the network level.  Really really secure information is on a  computer with no network connection...

There is the theory that the user, having just one password to use for their OpenID account, has the possibility to choose a decent strength password, less likely when they have to remember x passwords.

Comment: I use a password manage, LastPass to accomplish the idea of using very strong passwords on every site with only one strong password to remember.  Works well, but the interface would be difficult for non-technically oriented users.

Answer (score 4):

OpenID is technically sound, but can be baffling for some users. I recommend browsing through the responses to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410085/what-reasons-are-there-not-to-use-openid) question. For very private information I would be cautious about using OpenID because:

- Since the login is being used so widely and so frequently there are more opportunities for the password to be accidentally disclosed. A particular worry would be if another OpenID-enabled site which the user is registered on one day asks them for their actual password...some users might enter it without thinking, not realizing that they are circumventing the OpenId security model.
- If *you* have doubts about the security of OpenID, users might also have these doubts. From a business point of view, is it worth the risk of being *perceived* as insecure? (Of course, this is at least better than the other way around -- bad security being perceived as safe!)

There is a trend towards offering OpenID login on social networking sites and such, but I doubt we will see it being adopted very much for protecting extremely sensitive data.

Answer (score 3):

OpenID itself is secure, however due to its decentralised nature it often assumes that three servers are "trusted". If these servers are not trustworthy then your security is gone.

For instance, if you use your own website as an identifier but delegate authentication to a 3rd party provider, then if your website, *or* the identity provider, *or* the consumer server is penetrated, then the information is not secure.

If you want to use OpenID internally, and use *only* your own secure server as an OpenID provider, then you should be pretty secure. But if you want people to "bring their own OpenID account" then OpenID is not the right choice.

Comment: +1 Most people use an OpenID identity provided by Google, Yahoo, etc., so at the very least Google could theoretically break into some of your site's user accounts. (Using OpenID internally is an interesting idea, though in reality you'd probably choose a more centralized security model, e.g. Kerberos or Standford WebAuth).

Answer (score 3):

In general, it's not really any more o less secure than normal user/password authentication, but with one major difference (IMO).  OpenID allows a user to login via multiple different methods (Google, AOL, Yahoo, etc..).  If someone were to crack it, they'd have to go after each individual service.  You have the option to not allow certain services to participate, in the event you found one of them to be less secure.